# Button that once clicked goes to new email inbox

Tags: web-part

I need to create a button that when clicked it brings up a new email to a specific address.  I tried inserting an image but I cannot put a hyperlink to an email just to a presentation or document.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hyperlink to the address "mailto:address@domain.com" - [here's a tutorial with full syntax](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-create-a-mailto-link-3466469).